# How to use a small board computer's gpio to close a switch on an external device

Tags: transistors, switches, gpio

I'm using an Odroid XU4. It outputs 1.8V on the GPIOs. I have a USB2 Hub connected to it which has its own power supply (connected, alongside the Odroid to a pico PSU). Problem is, it has a physical tac switch to turn it on and off.

I want the Odroid to 'press' the switch after it is powered up via the gpio (I'll write a small script). The voltage across the switch is 3V when open, 0V when closed.

I'm guessing I need to use a transistor, but research is just confusing me more (I think electrical engineers think on another level...). Could anyone give some advice on how to achieve this? Pretend you're talking to a 10 year old who can solder.... I have a selection of transistors, so a model number may be helpful.

Comment: We can't suggest a transistor because we don't know what the switch actually connects and disconnects inside the hub. Is it AC power, DC power, if latter, does it switch the high side or low side of the supply, and is it referenced to ground? How many amps it must switch and how much voltage drop is tolerated? If unsure, it might be impossible to know which type of transistor would be suitable for switching in this case.

Comment: It's DC, as implied in the question. I don't know what you mean by high and low side - it's 3V open and 0V closed. How would I know if it's "referenced to ground"? How would I find out the other questions? I have a multimeter.

Comment: the physical switch can connect/disconnect the positive _or_ negative line to turn the hub off, and that matters a lot when choosing a transistor. If it disconnects the negative, you need a logic-level n-channel mosfet or an npn bjt. If it's switching the positive voltage, then you'll need to do some homework with articles/videos about "using transistor as a switch".

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a relay with a NPN transistor with a 200 Ohm resistor between the output and base of the transistor. The emitter is connected to all the grounds. The collector goes to the relay coil, the other side of the coil can go to whatever voltage is reasonable, probably 5V from the hub. You will need to place a diode across the relay coil with the cathode connected to +. For a circuit check this image out. http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Relay-driver-circuit.php It has an explanation and a diagram.